# My pet rat won't stop reopening his wound

Tags: health, injury, skin-condition, rat

My rat has this big bump on his shoulder that he made into a wound and he won't stop reopening it. He's 2 years old, so I'm scared to stress him out too much with excessive treatment. What to do?

Comment: Has a vet ever looked at the bump to see what it actually is? If there's an inflammation, it might be so itchy that your rat has to constantly lick or scratch the spot.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to prevent reopening is an e-collar (these exist for rodents) that will prevent him from licking. You could also use a bandage, but rats are fastidiously clean and he may try to remove it.